# How to use the Solr Data Import Handler to index a MySQL table?

Tags: mysql, solr, lucene, dataimporthandler

When I try to import a mysql table by loading this in the browser:

```
http://192.168.136.129:8983/solr/dataimport?command=full-import
```

I get this error:

```
HTTP ERROR 404

Problem accessing /solr/dataimport. Reason:

    NOT_FOUND

Powered by Jetty://
```

I'm following this tutorial from the official Solr wiki to get started with the DIH:

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DIHQuickStart

As per the tutorial I added this to my solrconfig.xml:

```
<requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
  <lst name="defaults">
    <str name="config">data-config.xml</str>
  </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

in data-config.xml I have the following:

```
<dataConfig>
  <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" 
              driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
              url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/site" 
              user="root" 
              password="123"/>
  <document>
    <entity name="profiles" 
            query="select user_id,about,music,movies,occupation from profiles">
    </entity>
  </document>
</dataConfig>
```

And these are the fields defined in my schema.xml:

```
  <fields>
    <field name="user_id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
    <field name="about" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
    <field name="music" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
    <field name="movies" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
    <field name="occupation" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />  
    <field name="text" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>
  </fields>

  <uniqueKey>user_id</uniqueKey>
```

So what am I doing wrong? I imagine it may have something to do with the data-config.xml file. In it I don't know if a certain path to the MySQL driver is being assumed. I downloaded the MySQL JDBC driver from here:

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/3.1.html

and put it in my `/solr/lib` directory.

When I downloaded the driver and extracted it there was a bunch of folders inside one folder called "mysql-connector-java-3.0.17-ga".

I do notice that inside that there is a dir called: `com` and inside that `mysql` and inside that `jbdc` and inside that there is a file called `Driver.class`.

Is this what is being referenced from data-config.xml? If so why isn't the initial directory not mentioned.

Basically I have no idea what the issue is, can someone help please.

Comment: Are you working with multiple cores? Do you have a `solr.xml` file within your solr home?

Comment: Go to http://192.168.136.129:8983/solr/admin/dataimport.jsp and check if the DIH GUI works

Comment: After you edited `solrconfig.xml`, did you restart solr?

Comment: Did you resolve this?  Which version of Solr are you using?

Comment: @bikedorkseattle no, just started using Sphinx and haven't looked back. It has out of the box support for indexing mysql tables.

Answer (score 5):

just make sure you have these lines of code in solrconfig.xml file

```
<lib dir="../../../contrib/dataimporthandler/lib/" regex=".*\.jar" />
<lib dir="../../../dist/" regex="solr-dataimporthandler-\d.*\.jar" />
```

make sure the path of those jar files and those jar files should be available physically at that path. If you don't have then please add that and try to restart the tomacat server and hopefully it will be resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old but I have recently had an occasion to set it up and had similar problems using Bitnami (Windows).

1. In `\dist` make sure you have **dataimporter** and **mysqlconnector**:

solr-dataimporthandler-4.9.0.jar

mysql-connector-java-5.1.32-bin.jar

2. In `\contrib\dataimporthandler\lib`

   activation-1.1.1.jar

   mail-1.4.3.jar
3. In your collection solrconfig.xml should have

   ```
   <lib dir="../../contrib/dataimporthandler/lib/" regex=".*\.jar" />
   <lib dir="../../dist/" regex="solr-dataimporthandler-.*\.jar" />  
   <lib dir="../../dist/" regex="mysql-connector-java-.*\.jar"/>
   ```

and:

```
  <requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="config">db-data-config.xml</str>
    </lst>
  </requestHandler>
```

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you are getting a NOT_FOUND error means that your Request Handler is not being Initialized. Make sure you restart solr after you insert the Request Handler.

Also make sure you have the data-config.xml saved in the same directory as your solrconfig.xml

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the absolute path for your `data-config.xml` location in your `solrconfig.xml` instead of the relative path.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing 'DataImportHandler.jar' in your Solr /lib folder, or your solr-conf.xml file is not aware of DataImportHandler classs.

Be sure that DataImportHandler is present there, to check 
hit

```
"http://localhost/solr/dataimport" ,
```

if you dont any error message on your browser that means solr-conf.xml is not aware of the location of SolrDataImportHandler.jar

Solution : Problem can be solved by using following line of code to solr-conf.xml

```
</requestHandler>
<requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
<lst name="defaults">
<str name="config">data-config.xml</str>
</lst>
</requestHandler>
```

For more information check out [this](http://www.beingjavaguys.com/2013/01/how-to-use-solr-data-import-handler-to.html).

There may be a case that your intial configuration are not perfect, take a look [Here to configure solr](http://www.beingjavaguys.com/2013/01/if-you-want-to-configure-solr4_19.html) before start importing.